# Swift- Weird Behaviour with Show Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

computer science student new to swift here. I'm probably struggling with something that is super rudimentary but I've been mulling over this for quite some time so I figured I need some help. I've been playing around with a really simple application that uses navigation controllers and a tab bar controller. For reference it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeanY.png).

It took a while but I discovered what an unwind segue is and I finally got all the navigation to work. All the buttons lead to the correct places, the navigation buttons work, etc. Just when I was moving on to the next part of my project, which is adding a background image to my root view, the navigation between my root view and tab bar controller became weird.

Normally, there's just a simple button that uses a simple show segue from the root view to the tab bar controller. But for some reason, it started to show vertically instead of the normal horizontal animation. It was working perfectly fine until I started adding a background image. I am completely lost as to what I did that led to this behaviour. I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071385/storyboard-segue-show-transition-vertical-from-bottom-instead-of-horizontal) thread here on stackoverflow that suggests the navigation controller might be nil but I'm not sure how to fix that.

I've tried deleting and making new outlets, etc but that hasn't worked. Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: A note about terminology: you're building your app in Apple's Interface Builder (IB). IB uses its own terminology for navigating that is not used in the programmatic context, like `segue`. A segue is IB's catch-all way of describing navigating between view controllers, which [programmatically] could either be a `push`, `present`, or `show`. The typical left-to-right navigating with the back button in the nav bar is `push` (forward) and `pop` (backward). The default bottom-to-top (modal) navigating that typically takes up the entire screen is `present` (up) and `dismiss` (down).

Comment: Thanks @slickdaddy for the info. It'll definitely make things clearer in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there's just a simple button that uses a simple show segue from the root view to the tab bar controller. But for some reason, it started to show vertically instead of the normal horizontal animation

It all depends on whether you've got a navigation controller. As you say rightly, if you have no navigation controller, a Show segue magically turns into a Present Modally segue, and that's what you are seeing when the segue does a vertical animation up from the bottom.

Comment: Thanks @matt. However, the button was working perfectly as a show segue for the longest time, so I wonder why its behaviour suddenly changed and how to fix that.

Comment: It's because you did something else having to do with the navigation controller. But I don't know what that was because I can't see your storyboard. Do your have a navigation controller in the storyboard at all? Launch your app and look at the console; are you getting a warning about the navigation controller having become unhinged from things?

Comment: Here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeanY.png) is a link to an image of my storyboard. I'm apparently not allowed to embed images yet so I apologize that the link wasn't very visible in my original post. The structure of my app is root->tab bar controller-->nav controller 1--->vc 1,-->nav controller 2--->vc 2. My console isn't showing any warnings either. Thanks for the patience!

Comment: the segue from root to tab bar controller is showing modally instead of showing

Comment: And that makes perfect sense because the root is not inside a navigation controller. That is what my answer says, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It seems I can solve the problem by just embedding root into a navigation controller and then hiding the navigation bar. But it's strange because I didn't have to do that before. Also I've read that apple doesn't like it when you have a hierarchy such as: nav controller->root-->tab bar--->nav controller

Comment: That is all exactly correct, including the last part. I do not understand what you're trying to do with this architecture; it's a very strange one. I've answered the question _that you asked_, but in my opinion you should now ask a completely new question in which you describe what you are _really_ trying to do and ask how to do it with a better architecture. If you do that, blip me here and I'll take a look!

Comment: I'm trying to basically make a restaurant menu where the root view is a kind of welcome page that the user will first see. Most of their time will be spent navigating through the tabs, where the menu items are. I guess the root view (welcome page) is just there to reset to for when there is a new user. Imagine it's the cover page of an actual menu in a restaurant. Thanks for the guidance. Much appreciated!

Comment: "I guess the root view (welcome page) is just there to reset to for when there is a new user" Well, what you had would be perfectly acceptable - a Present Modally segue where we just never come back to the welcome. A more sophisticated variant would br a "login screen" implementation where on subsequent launches we just _skip_ the welcome and start at the tab bar controller, or you could use a custom container controller that manages both the menu and the real interface (the tab bar controller and its children). Wrapping the navigation controller around the welcome is definitely wrong here.

Comment: I see. What you said makes a lot of sense! I'm going to try your suggestions. I guess my thought process for my original architecture is that say if a real restaurant decided to switch to digital menus and use this, they might want a welcome page for each customer but they might not necessarily want to relaunch the app every time, which is why I included an option to go back to the welcome page.

Comment: "which is why I included an option to go back to the welcome page" in which case your root-to-tab-bar-controller as a Present Modally segue remains perfectly reasonable. The user just never goes "back" because the user doesn't feel like it, and no harm done.